# I'm trying to print all even numbers from 10 to 40 using just a while loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to print all even numbers from 10 to 40 using just a while loop in Javascript. But when I execute the code in the Chrome Browser console I only see 10. Here is my code:

```
var x = 10;

while (x !== 41 && x % 2 == 0){
  console.log(x)
  x++
}
```

Comment: The loop stops as soon as `x % 2 == 0` is `false`, before you reach the point when `x !== 41` is `false`.

Comment: Just a quick note on while loops, conditions that break on strict equality are not the best.  `x !== 41` would be better done as `x < 41`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `x % 2 == 0` part. As soon as `x` becomes `11` the loop exits, because that condition evaluates to `false`. For the loop to continue, both conditions inside the `while()` parantheses have to evaluate to `true` as you are using the `&&` operator.

You should move that specific condition to an `if` statement inside the loop, like so:

```js
var x = 10;
while (x !== 41) {
  if (x % 2 == 0)
    console.log(x);
  x++;
}
```

The solution above keeps going until `x` is `41` in which case it will exit the loop and only runs the `console.log(x)` statement, if `x % 2` is equal to `0` (`x` is even).

A tip I would like to give you is to make a habit of using `===` instead of `==`. This will ensure your value is of the correct type (e.g. `x == 2` is `true` when `x` is `"2"` but `x === 2` will return `false` as the type is different) and might help you catch a few errors when debugging.

Another tip would be to use `x < 41` instead of `x !== 41`, it's more commonly used and it is easier to read through for most people.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so thoroughly and for the tips. I will make sure to remember them for now. @Angelos Chalaris

Comment: @I_am_a_Noob If you found an answer (only one, mine or anyone else's) more helpful than the rest and/or solving your problem, be sure to click the check mark under the votes counter to mark it as the accepted answer. This will help future readers find the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

As you are incrementing `x` by one, at first iteration the value of `x` becomes 11(odd) and the while condition is breaking. You can increment x by 2 as below.

```js
var x = 10;
while (x <= 40){
    console.log(x);
    x += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 10;
while(x < 41) {
  if(x % 2 == 0) {
    console.log(x);
  }
  x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you increase the **i** one by one, the value of the **i** becomes 11 (odd) on the first iteration, while the level breaks. Can be increased by **i** 2 as shown below.

```js
   i = 10
        while (i < 40) {
            i += 2;
            document.write("<br>",i);
            console.log(i)
        }
```

Comment: I like this answer the best but "i" needs to start at 8 in order to fulfill his requirements.

Comment: ya we need to start 8